# Creating a Archive in Wordpress Datewise for a Particular Category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, archive

In my site i would like to add a archive page or a custom page where i want to show posts from a particular category and that with a date wise format

like for example: i am in category : Technology
All post of a day will be shown at this page like i have written 3 posts only on that day.

The next page from navigation would be the previous date page .. which will show all posts from the previous day like 6 posts and so on

Example Page where I have seen this Functionality is : http://www.thedailybeast.com/cheat-sheet/

i want to show them in Title, little excerpt format ..

i think its possible with a custom page format ..

Hopefully i can get a quick response .. thnx

Answer (score 1):

you can probably either use your archive.php file or make a custom template file then use query_posts. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts

I would look at Example 2 under "Passing variables to query_posts" Something like this should work.

```
    <?php

$current_day = date('d');
$current_month = date('m');
$current_year = date('Y');

query_posts("cat=22&year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month&day=$current_day&order=ASC");
?>
<!-- put your loop here -->
```